# Implementing Ajax components with ASP.net Components

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax

it contains ajax uploader and text box and label
what i need to do it 
when upload complete what i wrote in text box go to label without refresh page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
        onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my C# code

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender,AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/nn/") + e.FileName;
    AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

the problem is that the ajax controller event cant feel .net components 
any help ?

Comment: Take a look at this link.  I noticed that it used a ThrobberID.  http://forums.asp.net/t/1810838.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to wrap your code in an update panel control.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
                    onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but it didnt work too ... the problem is that looks like the ajax uploader cant feel the .net components in c# code !